# Couldn't find table Java Glassfish

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish

I'm doing a distributed Java project. I had created new JDBC resource and connection pool in my GlassFish (Localhost:4848). My Java project is created through net bean. Under configuration settings (web.xml), on references tab -> resource references. My resource name is exactly points to the resource name I had created. I also use some test code to print out all my tables in data source.

**Print out all the tables from data source**

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/GiftDB");
con = ds.getConnection();
DatabaseMetaData md = con.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
   System.out.println("DEBUG(RS):" + rs.getString(3));
}
```

**Here's the output which is not what I expect**

```
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSALIASES
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSCHECKS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSCOLPERMS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSCOLUMNS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSCONGLOMERATES
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSCONSTRAINTS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSDEPENDS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSFILES 
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSFOREIGNKEYS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSKEYS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSPERMS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSROLES
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSROUTINEPERMS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSSCHEMAS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSSEQUENCES
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSSTATEMENTS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSSTATISTICS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSTABLEPERMS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSTABLES
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSTRIGGERS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSUSERS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSVIEWS
Info:   DEBUG(RS):SYSDUMMY1
```

I had add User, Password, URL field in MYSQLPool on GlassFish under additional properties tab. I also test the ping server and it works. I can access the database on third-party app like SequelPro.

I have no idea what is going on, the MySQL is connected successfully but the tables display output is unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Your request also gives you system tables that you don't want .

Narrow your search on the table type :

[DatabaseMetaData.html#getTableTypes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTableTypes())

> ResultSet getTableTypes()
>                           throws SQLException
>
> Retrieves the table types available in this database. The results are
>    ordered by table type. The table type is:
>
> TABLE_TYPE String => table type. Typical types are "TABLE", "VIEW",
>   "SYSTEM TABLE", "GLOBAL TEMPORARY", "LOCAL TEMPORARY", "ALIAS",
>   "SYNONYM".

```
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, null,new String[] {"TABLE"});
              System.out.println("List of tables: "); 
              while (rs.next()) {
                 System.out.println(
                    "   "+rs.getString("TABLE_CAT") 
                   + ", "+rs.getString("TABLE_SCHEM")
                   + ", "+rs.getString("TABLE_NAME")
                   + ", "+rs.getString("TABLE_TYPE")
                   + ", "+rs.getString("REMARKS")); 
              }
```